# Tutorials for .NET Remoting

Tags: .net, remoting

I've been looking around for some decent tutorials on .NET remoting (old style MarshallByRef), and have come across a couple, but nothing that I'm happy with. Does anyone know of any decent tutorials around?

Comment: You might consider rewording the title.  ".Net remoting" doesn't actually indicate you are looking for a tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out one and only Ingo Rammer's [.NET Remoting FAQ](http://www.thinktecture.com/resourcearchive). The information maybe some outdated as .NET Remoting.

And here is a PowerPoint presentation called [Introduction to .NET Remoting](http://www.ilmservice.com/twincitiesnet/Presentations/RemotingIntro.ppt) which helps you understand basic concepts behind remoting with figures/graphics.

Lastly here is the [Remoting Settings Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z415cf9a(VS.80).aspx) from MSDN if you frequently get lost (like me) in app.config files while configuring remoting.

Comment: Some nice stuff there, thanks

Comment: The powerpoint presentation is gone.

Comment: You can find the PowerPoint presentation I've mentioned backed up here: http://cl.ly/2D1Z1O0m1N3k2r0J2N3H

Answer (score 3):

I know you probably want something online, but I learnt this stuff from Ingo Rammer's book [Advanced .Net Remoting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590590252) which is very detailed, in depth and readable.

This is all .Net 1 stuff though (April 2002) so it may well be outdated and there may be better resources around these days.

Comment: I guess .NET Remoting itself is outdated, but it's what I've got to work with. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 1):

Plese check
[.NET Remoting](http://www.developer.com/net/cplus/article.php/1479761)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.71).aspx">MSDN - .NET Remoting Overview

Answer (score 1):

Here is my selection of related articles that I've bookmarked while searching on this topic myself: http://delicious.com/dreikanter/remoting First one is most comprehensive.

(I've tryed to copy those links here but spam prevention mechanism limited maximum links number to one per post :)